# What is the difference between clustered and non-clustered columnstore index with respect to rowstore data page concept

Tags: sql-server, columnstore

1. In **row based clustered index**: the entire table data (all columns) is ordered by clustered index column. Each **page** holds a particular amount of rows and all the column.
2. In **row based non-clustered index** - a data structure is created that holds the index column. Each **page** of the indexed column holds the row-wise values for that column and each row points back to the (another page) clustered index table key row or heap row (if no clustered index exists) for rest of the data.

I understand the concept of **columnstore index** - in the sense that there are row groups. Each row group contains one column segment (compressed) for every column in the table and there is a delta store to hold the Inserts/Updates until the next tuple mover process gets invoked. Based on the above 2 points of rowstore index **(page)**, **please can you tell me how it works in case of clustered and non-clustered columnstore index.**

Example - In case of Columnstore non-clustered index storage, is it conceptually same as rowstore non-clustered index - that is - separate page for the index column, the values of which points to heap or clustered index key.

Comment: Have you reviewed the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview)?

Comment: Yes, but it gives no information on concept of page, please can you guide me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In comparing rowstore vs columnstore, the term clustered means all columns and non-clustered means some columns (unless one included all columns). There is no other similarly between the disparate architectures of rowstore/columnstore organization. I personally don't even use the word index at all when referring to columnstore since the structure is optimized for scans rather than lookups and often leads to confusion.

Columnstore index segments, whether clustered or not, are essentially just compressed blobs of data stored in pages/extents. Rowstores, OTOH, have a record structure for each row to accommodate multiple columns of varying types and nullability, which is why they do not compress as well as columnstore data.

Comment: Hello @Dan, so do you mean that - in case of non-clustered column store index, the indexed column is stored in a separate page to the data table page? Does that mean the concept of non-clustered columnstore index is same as rowstore non-clustered index concept? And the column value from the index page, what do they point to? The rowgroup page?

Comment: With a non-clustered columnstore on a rowstore table, the row-locator is the clustered index key or the page/row/slot for a heap. This is the same pointer used in rowstore non-clustered indexes.

Comment: It is correct to say that there is performance improvement from using column-store index ONLY IF the query does an aggregation on that indexed column? My reasoning is because the indexed column (column-store) values will be closer together (on same or multiple pages) it will be quicker to get the data. Whereas if the query is to fetch data from multiple columns, then it will be comparatively slower because it needs to fetch the clustered index key from the column-store index to go to the row store table to fetch addn reqd info. In that case will the engine decide to ignore column-store index?

Comment: @variable, performance will likely depend much on how many rows must be fetched from the rowstore to get the results and the optimizer should ideally choose whether or not to use the columnstore index. Even without aggregation, it may be efficient to scan and filter columnstore index columns, and then retrieve rowstore columns for the final result.